# Using property introspection to find out if a double was declared as a NSTimeInterval?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say we have a class with an NSTimeInterval property:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSTimeInterval timeSpent;
}
@property (assign) NSTimeInterval timeSpent;
```

I can then get the type of the property like so:

```
const char * type = property_getAttributes(class_getProperty([MyClass class], "timeSpent"));
```

...where `type` would be something like: `Td, VtimeSpan` with "d" indicating that it's a double (which is normal since docs says `typedef double NSTimeInterval`)

Is there anything I can do in order to find out that the timeSpent property was initially declared as a NSTimeInterval?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `NSTimeInterval` is a `typedef` of `double`, which means that it is exactly the same type with a new name. This is convenient for writing self-documenting code, but it doesn't change anything about the type. (It also allows the underlying type to be changed while remaining source-compatible; they could change `NSTimeInterval` to be an alias of `float` or `_Complex double` or something else entirely, and your code wouldn't need to care.)

Is there a reason you care? Are you trying to write some generic code that treats time intervals differently than regular numbers? What's the end goal you have?

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation!
I have "entities" inheriting from a superclass which will populate the properties of the object from a "json-dictionary". If it's a double, it would just do a
self.doubleProperty = [.. doubleValue]
but if it's a NSTimeInterval it will asume the value in the dictionary isn't a double but a long long (equivalent to "ticks" in .NET since json comes from a .NET webservice) and do a:
self.timeIntervalProperty = [.. convertFromDotNetTicks].

Sounds weird? :)

Comment: That's not what an `NSTimeInterval` represents. It represents "seconds since January 1, 1970 12:00:00AM UTC." You should use (`new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(theTimeIntervalValue)`).

Comment: The type NSTimeInterval itself is just "Used to specify a time interval, in seconds" [see docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).   [aDate **timeIntervalSince1970** ] will return a time interval  that represents "the interval between the receiver and the first instant of 1 January 1970, GMT", right? But yes, I do a similar conversion as the one you gave at the server side when dealing with dates.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I am not quite sure why I posted what I did. I should have said "an `NSTimeInterval` measures a time interval in seconds, not ticks."